# Joining MS SQL tables in a JDBC query

Tags: sql, jdbc, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using a JDBC query to an MS SQL database as a datasource for a view. The datasource is something like:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xe:jdbcQuery connectionName="mssql" sqlQuery="select * from table" var="jdbcData1">
    </xe:jdbcQuery>
</xp:this.data>
```

I can add parameters to this (eg: where col=?) and it all works fine, but I can't manage to get a join working. Is it possible to join two tables in this manner?

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement with the join that you are attempting?

Comment: I've tried a few: as simple as `select * from table1 join table2` or adding conditions/parameters `select * from table1 join table2 on table1.col = table2.col where param=?`, none have worked.

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting if any?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work without any problems as its just crating the Statement to run against the  JDBC Server.